# Scripting backup of SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to follow this link to automate my database backups:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019698/how-to-schedule-and-automate-backups-of-sql-server-databases-in-sql-se

I have loaded the stored procedure in my `[master]` database and have created a batch file to execute the stored procedure.

When running the batch file below using SQL Server authentication, I don't get any output in my backup location

```
SQLCMD -S .\servername -U username -P password 
       -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases  @databaseName='databasename', @backupType=’F’, @backupLocation = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup'"
```

I have made sure that the username login has the appropriate role membership for the database I am trying to backup (`db_backupoperator` is selected, together with `db_owner`).

I am also not sure how to generate a log file to see if there are any tracebacks - the batch file just completes with no output.

Here are the server properties:

```
Product: Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1 (7601)
Platform: NT INTEL X86
Version: 10.50.1617.0 RTM
```

I appreciate very much if someone would help me out, thank you.

Comment: There are still should be some output to a command shell... Some error messages or exceptions..

Comment: Using RTM version? That's not good. RTM is not supported. The last SP is on life-support and will soon be unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
@backupLocation = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup'
```

In documentation is written how you should specify the path:

Example1

```
sqlcmd -S .\EXPRESS –E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases @backupLocation='D:\SQLBackups\', @backupType='F'"
```

Note the last slash in the path.

Now, the code simplified that was executed looks like this:

```
declare @backupLocation nvarchar(200) = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup',
        @DBNAME sysname = 'databasename',
        @BackupFile varchar(100)

SET @BackupFile = @backupLocation+REPLACE(REPLACE(@DBNAME, '[',''),']','')+ '_FULL_'+ '20190222'+ '.BAK'
select @BackupFile
```

So the file name is

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backupdatabasename_FULL_20190222
```

And you should look for it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\`